# Add a time amount to another time amount

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to add a time to another time.

For instance:

01:52:00.0000000 + 00:59:00.0000000 = 02:51:00.0000000

I know I can't do this directly with a "+".

I've tried dateadd but I can't seem to get that to work for me either.

Please help.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Seems ideal to do this before or after calling the SQL query. What language are you using?

Comment: Why is DATEADD not working? Can you show and example? What have you tried?

Comment: Can the sum of these times be equal to or greater than 24 hours?

Comment: 11PM + 9PM = is what? (A time value is a point of time. You can't add them together. You can add an interval (i.e. duration) to a time, you can also add two intervals.)

Comment: I think you should please show your real sample input and expected result to clarify your issue.

Comment: The language is in the tags - tsql.
I have tried converting both to seconds and adding.
I have generated these two times so they can never go over 24hrs.

Comment: Probably because you mention your attempt at `DATEADD` but don't show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `CAST` your both times to entire dates. This allows to use `DATEADD`:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, 
DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST('00:59:00' AS DATETIME)),
CAST('01:52:00' AS DATETIME)) AS TIME)
```

This ugly casting could and should be avoided by just generating whole dates instead of the time only. You could just add the current day.

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEPART(MINUTE, '2022-11-23 00:59:00'),
'2022-11-23 01:52:00') AS TIME)
```

Here you need to pay attention to do not confuse day with month and run into a conversion error.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JjGhA64k)

Please note I do not recommend to do such "calculations" at all in SQL. This could be much better done in your application.

You have written "I have generated these two times"...I don't know where/how you did this, but this generation should better also do this calculation rather than using SQL for that.